# как пользоваться for, range, return?

Tags: python

объясните вот эти вот:

```
for 
return 
range
```

объясните, пожалуйста, как ими пользоваться

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как бы мне ни хотелось отправить автора вопроса почитать любой учебник по Python, тем не менее:

1. `for` – в простейшем варианте применения (а их есть довольно много)
       создаёт цикл вот так:   
       `for i in  """здесь последовательность значений (любых)""" :
               """здесь тело цикла"""`

   Таким образом, `i` поочерёдно принимает значения из
   последовательности и потом выполняется тело цикла (любые другие
   действия)
2. `return` – вкратце используется для возвращения значения из функции.
   Объяснение о том, что такое функции и зачем они нужны слишком длинно
   для ответа на вопрос, в конце прикреплю ссылку
3. `range` – опять же, вкратце, функция, создающая числовые
   последовательности (а может и не только числовые, точно не помню).
   Например `range(5)` вернёт `[0,1,2,3,4]` (как видно,
   последовательность создаётся от нуля до переданного числа минус 1)

**ОЧЕНЬ РЕКОМЕНДУЮ ПОЧИТАТЬ:**

1. [Учебник 1](https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python)
2. [Учебник 2](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/1.1.php) (на мой взгляд, лучше)

P.S. Автору этого вопроса и всем новичкам, кто это прочитает: прежде чем задавать вопрос на Stackoverflow следует САМОМУ(ОЙ) предпринять какие-либо попытки разобраться в материале. Читайте книжки, наконец. По таким элементарным вопросам в интернете **горы** литературы, в которых профессиональные и гораздо более осведомлённые авторы "разжёвывают" всё до мельчайших подробностей, не оставляя непонятным ни единого шага.